# Parallelism hint with HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-storm

I am working on the apache storm and using HDFS. If I use parallelism hint for bolt  1 and it is creating one file, writing data to file and working fine. But when I increase parallelism hint for bolt to 3, it is creating 3 files and writing data to only one file.

My application have one spout and two bolts(Xbolt and Yblot)
Parallelism hint are as follows 
Spout 1 , Xbolt 1, Ybolt 3

application flow
Spout --> Xbolt --> Ybolt --> file(s)

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder(); 
BoltDeclarer boltDeclarer;

int parallelismHint = 0;
parallelismHint = SpoutLogic.determineParallelismHint(config);

builder.setSpout("TOPIC_ID", new Spout(), parallelismHint); 
parallelismHint = XBoltLogic.determineParallelismHint(config); 
boltDeclarer = builder.setBolt("XBOLT_ID", new XBolt(), parallelismHint);    
boltDeclarer.shuffleGrouping("TOPIC_ID","XBoltMessage"); 
parallelismHint = HDFSBoltLogic.determineParallelismHint(config); 
boltDeclarer = builder.setBolt("HDFSBOLT_ID",new HDFSBolt(), parallelismHint);
boltDeclarer.fieldsGrouping("XBOLT_ID","XBoltMessage",new Fields("Table")); StormSubmitter.submitTopology("MyTopologyName", config, builder.createTopology());
```

Comment: what's your connection pattern? can it be, that all data is routed to a single bolt only?

Comment: @gudivinay provide your driver code please

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, Yes all data is routed to single bot only.i.e HDFS bolt and I am using Abstract HDFS bolt for the writing the data to a file.

Comment: @Alex, Driver Code? sorry I am new to storm, I didn't get what exactly you are asking for, Could you please clarify me?

Comment: @gudivinay np, I mean can you post the body of your main method where you set bolts, spouts and submit topology

Comment: @gudivinay That is not what I meant. What connection pattern do you use between bolt -> HDFSBolt? shuffle? allGrouping? fieldGrouping?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax , thanks for clarification. Please find the code below and let me know,if any more info is needed from my end

Comment: @Alex, please find the above code and let me know I miss anything

Comment: @gudivinay Please edit your question instead of adding missing information as comments.

Comment: If you use fieldGrouping, it can happen that all data hashed to the bolt (even if this is unlikely). What is your key space for your fieldsGrouping attribute `"Table"` ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, I am reading the data from streams and that data may contain duplicate rows as well, So Instead of doing the fieldsGrouping by ID or any other column, I am using Table Name to group the data. Please let me know, If not reaching out to you correctly

Comment: Is the table name the same for all you records? If yes, it's obvious that all records go to the same bolt -- that is what fieldsGrouping does -- send all records with the same value of the grouping attributes to the same bolt.

Comment: Yes all records have the same table Name, but my problem is its not writing the data to all the three files. Correct me If I wrong @MatthiasJ.Sax,  According to the discussion, If Parallelism is 3 or 5 or n, it will create that number of Files, based on the grouping, it will write the data into those files. If it is field grouping it will just write to one File( based on the FiledType) and if Shuffle Grouping it will write data to multiple Files.

Comment: Yes. shuffle() would sent the data in round-robin fashion to the bolts.

Comment: Thanks alot @MatthiasJ.Sax and Alex for Helping me out. I will implement that way and get back If needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use fieldGrouping, it can happen that all data hashed to the bolt (even if this is unlikely).shuffle() would sent the data in round-robin fashion to the bolts.